# AssetManage instantiation

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.android

How to properly instantiate AssetManage?

I have a file that I'd like to load and I am getting an error.

Here is what I have:

```
     AssetManager assetManager = new AssetManager(handle);

     Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/calibri.ttf");

     this._textView.SetTypeface(tf, 0); // i just need a regular calibri, I added a file into the fonts folder and set it to AndroidAsset.
```

What should be a "handle" in this case?

Thank you

Comment: jpobst's answer is correct. The (IntPtr) constructors are for wrapping a pre-existing JNI object reference for use by managed code. You only need these constructors if you're using JNI/Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.

Comment: How about marking a correct answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
```

Answer (score 5):

If this is MonoDroid, Java's get*() syntax has been turned into .NET properties, so it's:

```
AssetManager assetManager = Resources.Assets;
```

Comment: There is also the Android.Content.Context.Assets property as well (this.Assets instead of this.Resources.Assets): http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=P:Android.Content.Context.Resources

Comment: No problem, someone had tagged this as monodroid, which is incorrect.